# Bought Ethreum with BTC, exchange freezed, sync freezed too

Tags: synchronization, bitcoin, exchanges, shapeshift

I've purchased ETH by BTC. My exchange stucked on "Awaiting Exchange" (like 2 hours now) and my Sync stucked at the same time (19%). What should I do now?

Thank you!

Comment: Pls help, still no clue, no ethereum ... nothing

Comment: From which application did you bought ether? @user10429

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: If you used Shapeshift, please contact their support including the transaction ID. If your wallet does not sync fast enough, consider using a different client.

Answer (score 1):

The bitcoin network is struggling to verify transactions. Try cancelling the transaction and re-sending with a higher miner fee.

Comment: Your sync is probably stuck for a different reason. Ask another question.